# How to generalize functions returning either a Dictionary or a List

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Im failing on an attempt to generalize a function which should fill either a List<> or a Dictionary<>. First of all the following does not compile:

```
T foo<T>() where T : ICollection, new()
{
  T t = new T();

  t.Add(1, 1);

  return t;
}
```

Error   1   'T' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Second of all, suppose if this would compile how could the "Add" be generalized?

```
t.Add(1, 1) // for dictionaries
and t.Add(1) // for Lists
```

Would be great if something is possible

Comment: How are you *actually* getting the keys and values? If you're filling a list, would you discard the keys or the values? Or populate it with key/value pairs? Wouldn't it be simpler to provide a sequence and allow the caller to call `ToDictionary` or `ToList`? Currently the question is too vague to be answered, to be honest.

Comment: You cannot use `Add` since it is not a part of the `ICollection` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, not the most elegant solution not sure if I would take this in production.
It reads an SQL server table from query that is passed in with Func<> and the Action object passed in as parameter is used to add objects to the collection.

```
public C Read<C, T>(Func<SqlConnection, SqlDataReader> func, Action<C, T> a)
    where C : ICollection, new()
    where T : EntityBase, new()
{
    C objects = new C();

    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = func(connection))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                T obj = new T();
                obj.PopulateFromReader(reader);
                a(objects, obj);
            }
        }
    }

    return objects;
}
```

called like this:

```
       Dictionary<Guid, DeliveryMoment> dic = _dalBO.Read<Dictionary<Guid, DeliveryMoment>, DeliveryMoment>(connection => { return CmdFactory.ReadDeliveryMoments(connection); }, (d, o) => { d.Add(o.DeliveryMomentId, o); });
```

What do you think? Too shady or acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

```
static T Temp<T>(params object[] obj) where T:ICollection, new ()
    {
        T s = new T();
        //TODO: validation for input values
        if (s is IDictionary)
        {
            ((IDictionary) s).Add(obj[0], obj[1]);
        }
        else if (s is IList)
        {
            ((IList)s).Add(obj[0]);
        }

        return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an extension method like the following

```
    public static void AddToCollection(this ICollection col, object value)
    {
        if (col is IDictionary)
        {
            ((IDictionary)col).Add(value, value);
        }
        else if(col is IList)
        {
            ((IList)col).Add(value);
        }
    }
```

and then replace

```
t.Add(1, 1);
```

with

```
t.AddToCollection(1);
```

Comment: If your dictionary is adding the same instance as both the key and value every time then you're simply using the wrong data structure, and *that* is his problem; he should just be using something like a `HashSet` instead, and then there is a method with a common signature to be used.

Comment: I'm assuming he knows what he wants and answered his question. Dictionary behaviour could be required after this initial set up.

Comment: Then the appropriate thing to do would be to have this function return a list or `IEnumerable` and let the caller do what they want with it, either populating a list or a dictionary.